# hover outline css bug on chrome and opera

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/L7rdyv6z/

if you hover above the `<tr>`s or rapidly move your mouse over them you might notice that the `.tr:hover{outline:5px solid #377abf;}` behaves weirdly. sometime only one side of the border will show, sometimes portions of sides.

I managed to take this screenshot. as you can see the lines remain even when my mouse is not over them.  i tried on opera and chrome with similar results
testing on my server or on jsfiddle creates the same results.  what could possibly be doing this?  Is it my computer?

i have windows 7 with chrome running in 32bit.
computer restart did nothing
[image]

Comment: It's most certainly is an issue with the rendering engine on your system. I've just checked it on Chrome, Firefox and Midori on Linux and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: ah. maybe a computer restart might solve it

Comment: I have the same issue on Win7 32bit with Chrome 36 :/

Comment: yeah but it does the same thing on opera, but not on firefox and ie

Comment: May it's an issue with windows systems in general. What is your processor brand?

Comment: core i5-4200m processor  and a nividia graphics card

Comment: win7 64bit, opera = no issues